# atomic file creation on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems, createfile, atomic

I need to create a file if it does not exist, in a way that  another process trying to create this file would fail. I need the file be considered "created" even before the creating process finished writing the actual data to it.

I read about `O_EXCL` flag to `open()`, so it seems that the solution exists, I have a few questions however:

1. do you have experience with this technique? How good is it? (I guess I can't have a DB-level atomicity, but but good enough is... well, enough)
2. should I immediately close the file after `open()` so that it is considered created, and then reopen it for writing?
3. are there any subtleties to be aware of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [open() man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) says your method may fail on NFS.

From the section on O_EXCL:

> When used with O_CREAT, if the file
>   already exists it is an error and the
>   open() will fail. In this context, a
>   symbolic link exists, regardless of
>   where it points to. O_EXCL is broken
>   on NFS file systems; programs which
>   rely on it for performing locking
>   tasks will contain a race condition.

And it suggests a more general solution:

> The solution for performing atomic
>   file locking using a lockfile is to
>   create a unique file on the same file
>   system (e.g., incorporating hostname
>   and pid), use link(2) to make a link
>   to the lockfile. If link() returns 0,
>   the lock is successful. Otherwise, use
>   stat(2) on the unique file to check if
>   its link count has increased to 2, in
>   which case the lock is also
>   successful.

See the "Using Files as Locks" section of [this Web page](http://www.dwheeler.com/secure-programs/Secure-Programs-HOWTO/avoid-race.html) for more details on the various issues and approaches.

Comment: yes, i've seen this, so my questions were for the case I am not working with NFS. Also, the alternative solution is obscure for me - how creating a **unique** file per process helps 2 processes see that they are trying to work with the same file? If you understand this, care to explain?

Comment: link and unlink calls on NFS are not idempotent or synchronized.  Use mkdir instead.

Comment: @davka:  this method is using a link as a lock.  Whatever file the link currently points to, "owns" the lock.  (And each file is unique to a process, so you you have process locking).

Comment: @davka – [`fcntl`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) is supposed to work over NFS, so as an alternative you could use that to synchronise your processes on the write instead of on the open.

Answer (score 1):

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/) says:

> If O_CREAT and O_EXCL are set, open() shall fail if the file exists.
>   The check for the existence of the file and the creation of the file if
>   it does not exist shall be atomic with respect to other threads
>   executing open() naming the same filename in the same directory with
>   O_EXCL and O_CREAT set.

So other processes using `O_EXCL` will consider it opened as soon as it is created.

Comment: thanks, this is more unambiguous. I wandered whether the file is considered "created" right after `open()`. This seem to say that yes

Comment: @davka – I guess it says "yes, it should be", but I don't see any point in having the flag at all without this guarantee. [BSD manpages](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=open) say "This may be used to implement a simple exclusive access locking mechanism." Without the guarantee that wouldn't work.